# How do I open and close NERDTree (toggle NERDTree view) using a single keystroke?

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

Sometimes in my workflow, I might want to open or search for a file on the go.

I'd like to map a single key (say <kbd>F6</kbd>) to open and close NERDTree (*i.e.*, I want to toggle the NERDTree view). Also, I'd like NERDTree to display hidden files and folders in its toggled view, and I'd also like it to close automatically when I open a file for editing, if that is possible.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Please keep in mind that it's better to ask multiple questions instead of one with different points. i.e. here you could ask another question regarding the hidden files and folders, because the main question is definitely about the toggle (which you already got an answer for). Also don't forget to read the plugin documentation and to spend hours in `:h` ;)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In your `vimrc` add

```
nmap <F6> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

where `<F6>` is the key you want to map.

Comment: Works great but how do I show hidden files and folders at the same time?

Comment: @evil_potato `shift + i` will toggle hidden files. If you want to set as a default behaviour add `let NERDTreeShowHidden=1` to your `.vimrc`

Comment: @evil_potato Also to close automatically when open a file for editing add `let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen=1` to your `.vimrc`

Answer (score 27):

To open NerdTree :

```
:NERDTreeFocus
```

To switch beetween nerdtree and file opened windows :

```
ctrl + ww (double w)
```

or

```
ctrl + w + (h/j/k/l)
```

To close NerdTree (in nerdtree window) :

```
:q
```

Answer (score 7):

This would do exactly what you've asked for:

```
nnoremap <silent> <expr> <F6> g:NERDTree.IsOpen() ? "\:NERDTreeClose<CR>" : bufexists(expand('%')) ? "\:NERDTreeFind<CR>" : "\:NERDTree<CR>"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're stuck with a Mac with the absent function keys (touchbar), you can toggle NERDTree by mapping the `Ctrl` key like so within your `.vimrc` file:

```
map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

Save the changes, open Vim, and then toggle NERDTree with `Ctrl`+`n`.

Comment: This <C-n> worked on Linux as well, <F6> didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to close NERDTree window make sure you are inside the NERDTree menu. You can switch windows by using `ctrl+w` then type `:q` to close NERDTree window so that you will be left with the window for editing your code.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but what about opening it again, do I need to map another key or is there a native shortcut that will open NERDTree again?

Answer (score 0):

The following function tracks open netrw buffers and calls `Lexplore` accordingly. Add it to your `.vimrc` and pick your mapping key.

```
let g:NetrwIsOpen=0

function! ToggleNetrw()
    if g:NetrwIsOpen
        let i = bufnr("$")
        while (i >= 1)
            if (getbufvar(i, "&filetype") == "netrw")
                silent exe "bwipeout " . i 
            endif
            let i-=1
        endwhile
        let g:NetrwIsOpen=0
    else
        let g:NetrwIsOpen=1
        silent Lexplore
    endif
endfunction

noremap <silent> <F2> :call ToggleNetrw()<CR>
```

Comment: Could you explain how it is better than the command `NERDTreeToggle` which comes with NerdTree?

Comment: @statox - the idea is to open with a singe key (or probably two keys combination) - instead of typing ":" + "N" + "E" + "R" + "D" + "T" + "r" + "e" + "e" and hit `Enter`. Exactly what I'm after right now :)

Comment: @peshohristov If the goal is to reduce the number of keystrokes I think a mapping in the lines of `nnoremap <single-key> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>` does the trick, that is why I asked OP to give more details on the usefulness of their answer.